# C++ fork() looks strange on linux terminal

Tags: c++, c, linux, fork

I am trying to use `fork()` in C++.
However, it looks strange on the terminal.

as u can see on the screen shot, my code just outputs its process's PID and whether it is a child or a parent.
But when the parent process is finished, the Child's output gets printed on the new prompt.

And most importantly, it still waits for my command after the who program is done.

I do not understand why it still waits for input as shown in the picture.

[image: My code and its output]

Comment: All code and output should be pasted *here* and not linked on an external site.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, include the text as text instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fork()` does not spawn an "empty" process binary. It creates a clone of the calling process and both processes then run in parallel. Which means that if the forked process doesn't `execve` into another process image or terminates you're ending up with two copies of the same program in almost the same state running alongside. The only difference between them is that the child gets a 0 as return value of fork, while the parent sees the child process PID.

You surely know these SciFi stories where a person suddenly gets copied down to the quantum level and meets their original and they get into an argument to who is the original and who's the copy. That's *exactly* the situation parent and child process are after a fork.

> And most importantly, it still waits for my command after the who program is done.

No, it does not. It just looks like that on your console: The parent process terminates and thus the shell will print the prompt. Then the child process prints its stuff after the prompt. Try calling with with a sleep, i.e.

```
~/... > ./hw3 ; sleep 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much!
I wish I had enough reputations to vote u up.

Comment: @JustinOh Voted it up for you. You can accept the answer if it answers your question, and get +2 yourself. :-)